# Publish chrome and firefox extension in private mode

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, browser, firefox-addon

I created a browser extension for my coworkers that enhances the system we use daily but can't modify it.

So far we've been using it locally. Everyone has a copy of the files on their own machine and everytime there's an update I have to notify everyone to manually update it.

I'd like to publish it on the chrome and firefox stores but I would rather not make it public.

Is there a way to publish it privately, so only the people with a link could access and download it ?

Comment: for chrome world the answer is YES: see https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/update/ (visibility section-image).
For FF I don't know, you have to check by yourself in addons.mozilla.org docs.

Comment: FF answer is here https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/publish/self-distribution/ -- there are a few ways to go about it